# Visual C++ System String, Return a reference to the character at position in the string

Tags: string, c++-cli

i would like to get a specific character of a string in visual c++, like this example (c++):

```
string str = "String";
cout << str.at(4);    // The member function String::at  will return 'i'
```

But this is possible, if i use the class string

In visual c++, i would like to use the System::String

```
label1->Text = "String";
String^ text = label1->Text;      //Get text of label
Messagebox::Show( text->at(4) );  //Return the character 'i'
```

error:  'at' : is not a member of 'System::String'

This means that the function at is not a member of System::String... Is there any other function that i could use?

I am using Visual studio c++ 2010... The application is made in windows forms

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> none of the 21 overloads could convert all the argument types

Right.  But read the error message carefully, none of the overloads of the **Show() method** applies.  It isn't complaining about operator[], that one is fine and does what you'd expect it to do.  Which makes sense if you think about it a bit, you'd never use a MessageBox to show a single character.  Only a string.  So this works:

```
  String^ text = "String";
  Char ch = text[4];
  MessageBox::Show(gcnew String(ch, 1));
```

But of course you'd never write code like this so do take a step back and review what you are *really* trying to accomplish.  Do avoid assuming that the STL template classes resemble their .NET equivalents, having a garbage collector makes collection classes much simpler to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Try just using array indexing:

```
Messagebox::Show( text[4] );  //Return the character 'i'
```

**Update**

As Hans Passant pointed out, the issue with this solution isn't the array indexing. It's trying to pass a Char to Messagebox::Show, which takes a string. See his solution for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are giving the fifth *codeunit* in the System::String. While that is more like your C++ code, it might not be what you want.

A System::String is a codeunit-counted, sequence of Unicode characters in the UTF-16LE encoding. In this encoding, the codepoint for a character might be one or two code-units. So, directly indexing into a System::String jumps past an unknown number of characters and if you land at or in the middle of a codepoint that has two code-units you only get half of the codepoint.

If you want the fifth ***character***, you need to use the [System.Globalization::StringInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.StringInfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

```
new StringInfo(text)->SubstringByTextElements(4, 1)
```

Obviously, it returns a System::String because System::Char is a code-unit type and is insufficient to hold a codepoint.

Note: this class handles combining forms and characters that require more than one code-unit for their codepoint.

Try in on "na\u0308ive". It'll give "ä" as the second text element.